# Android AIDLTokenType.IDENTIFIER expected, got rpc error in AIDL file

Tags: android, android-service, aidl, android-service-binding

I have such aidl file:

```
package com.my.service;

import com.my.common.rpc.OnNextListener;
interface IService {
    oneway void acceptStateListener(in OnNextListener l);
}
```

And I got an error in my Android Studio: 
`AIDLTokenType.IDENTIFIER expected, got 'rpc'`

What's wrong here? Where I can find definitive tutorial about AIDL syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems issue with the string "rpc" in your package name. Please rename it, it should work fine. I got similar error for the string "in" in my package.